# Java - Array notation in generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have just come across [this code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/AbstractPipeline.java#655) in the Streams Java API source code and I am totally confused as to what it means-:

```
IntFunction<E_OUT[]> generator
```

How can a generic parameter in Java have the array braces? What does that even mean?

Does it mean IntFunction will output an array of E_OUT parameters? I thought Java forbade generic arrays.

Whats going on here?

How can I use the array notation in a generic argument? Can someone provide a simple example of this?

Comment: Yes, it means that `generator` has an `apply` method with an `int` parameter that returns an array of `E_OUT`.  Check the Javadoc for `IntFunction`.  I'm not sure what your question is about.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem My question is about how you can use the array notation in generics. I will edit my question to include this.

Comment: Well, in `IntFunction<R>`, `R` can be any reference type you like.  That includes array types.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem But how do I create a generic array in Java? Isn't that illegal syntax?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem you mean E_OUT is a real class?

Comment: No.  I worded that badly, sorry.  Here, you've got a method parameter whose type is `IntFunction<E_OUT[]>`, and there's nothing wrong with that, because we're never asked to instantiate an `E_OUT[]`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am not understanding. Just tell me is `E_OUT` a generic type parameter or is there a class called `E_OUT`?

Comment: When you're running the code in the `AbstractPipeline` class, you have some kind of pipeline to be running the code on.  Let's just say it's an `AbstractPipeline<String,Integer,FancyStream>`.  Then this method parameter would have to be an `IntFunction<Integer[]>`.  So when you're running the code, the actual type that `E_OUT` represents  has already been decided.

Comment: @ng.newbie to answer your question, It's a type parameter declared on class level. If you want to see an example, just check an implementation of this class.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yes but having `IntFunction<Integer[]>` means that somewhere in the function I will be instantiating an `Integer` array correct? So that means I am creating a generic array somewhere right? Which is clearly illegal, what am I missing?

Comment: No, you're not creating a generic array.  You can have a perfectly ordinary non-generic function that returns an `Integer[]`.  Then pass it to the `makeNodeBuilder` method of your `AbstractPipeline<String,Integer,FancyStream>`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem got it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are just syntactical sugar to ease the issue with datatypes and type casting. Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) every generic would be of type Object anyway **during runtime**. Let's have a look at a little example:

**Test.java with generics:**

```
public class Test<E>
{

  private E temp;

  public void setVar(E var) 
  {
    this.temp = var;
  }

  public E getVar() 
  {
    return temp;
  }

}
```

This structure allows us to use the class like this:

```
public static  void main( String[] args )
  {
    Test<String>  t = new Test<>();
    t.setVar( "Hello World" );
    String str = t.getVar();
    System.out.println( str );
  }
```

**Test.java without the use of generics:**

```
public class Test
{

  private Object temp;

  public void setVar(Object var) 
  {
    this.temp = var;
  }

  public Object getVar() 
  {
    return temp;
  }
}
```

This structure has some major flaws. For example I can now store any object i like by calling the `set(Object var)` method since there is no generic which would define the type **during compile time**.

```
public static  void main( String[] args )
{
  Test  t = new Test();
  t.setVar( "Hello World" );
  String str = (String) t.getVar();
  System.out.println( str );
}
```

As you can see I now have to cast `t.getVar()` to a String since the returned object is of type `Object`. The issue with that is that you must be a 100% vertain that you cast it to the right datatype. Otherwise a `ClassCastException` might be thrown.

TL;DR: Eases the pain of casting. A lot.

Answer (score 0):

As the source code comments,In the IntFunction, the R refer to result, E_OUT[] is the result type.

```
package java.util.function;

/**
 * Represents a function that accepts an int-valued argument and produces a
 * result.  This is the {@code int}-consuming primitive specialization for
 * {@link Function}.
 *
 * <p>This is a <a href="package-summary.html">functional interface</a>
 * whose functional method is {@link #apply(int)}.
 *
 * @param <R> the type of the result of the function
 *
 * @see Function
 * @since 1.8
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntFunction<R> {

    /**
     * Applies this function to the given argument.
     *
     * @param value the function argument
     * @return the function result
     */
    R apply(int value);
}
```

As the List, The E refer to Element

```
/**
 * @param <E> the type of elements in this list
 */
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {}
```